# Organizing Lore

Tags: worldbuilding-process

I have been compiling some lore notes on my world by hand for some time now. I realize they will only get more extensive and am currently looking for a way to organize them digitally. Does anyone have any suggestions on an efficient way to do this? I am looking for anything from software to help with organization to suggestions on an abstract storage structure that comprehensive and maybe even prompts further lore development.

EDIT: I am not searching for a pure software solution but rather an *algorithmic* solution to better organize my data, whether it be implemented im software already available or not. I apologize if my question was not clear enough on that front.

Comment: If you were to go the software route, what are some basic (or advanced) features you'd want to have?

Comment: Always keep a back up of your files. Ideally on an external drive or a USB key.

Comment: @Seth The features I would mostly desire would be organizing a large body of information while maintaining relationships between them with a way to easily subdivide them into categories. I suppose it's much too late for that now as the question was closed.

Comment: Leon can you explain what you are wanting an algorithmic solution to accomplish?  I am not sure how an algorithm can accomplish the organization of non-standard data.

Comment: @James Perhaps algorithm wasn't the best word to use here as design pattern seems to be a better fit. What I am looking for is a general idea of how organize information that is easily scalable and maintainable. I am still unsure how to express this idea better, so if that still doesn't help, I will do more research and post a post a question when I better understand. Thank you all for the help, regardless :)

Comment: This mostly sounds like you are trying to create a database, and there are many available, although the Microsoft Office "Access" database is probably the most common one for relatively small projects like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Formatting

I (indirectly) use HTML, but instead of writing straight in HTML, I write with [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) which is text formatting language that Stack Exchange uses (you wrote your question with markdown, I'm wrote this answer with markdown, etc).

You can make [links](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19594/organizing-lore), **bold**, *italics*, lists, insert images, etc.

So far, my answer looks like this:

`# Formatting`

`Similar to what [Philip](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/19598/9708) said:`

`I (indirectly) use HTML, but instead of writing straight in HTML, I write with [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) which is the text formatting language that Stack Exchange uses (you wrote your question with markdown, I'm wrote this answer with markdown, etc).`

`You can make [links](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19594/organizing-lore), **bold**, *italics*, lists, insert images, etc.`

`...`

This is quite readable even if you don't know the syntax.

## Organisation

Similar to what [Philip](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/19598/9708) said:
An old fashioned HTML/Markdown index could link to different sections of lore.

For my story, I have separate sections for alien creatures, alien cultures, things happening on Earth, etc. You should have top headings, ("Alien cultures") with subheadings that have a short description and link to more complete information:

Your index might look like this:

> ### Alien cultures
>
> #### [Aliens from Foobar](http://www.example.com/aliens-from-foobar.html)
>
> - Prefer to eat spicy food.
> - Think 'guacamole' is inherently funny
> - Enjoy abducting cows
>
> #### [Aliens from Barbaz](http://www.example.com/aliens-from-barbaz.html)
>
> - Sworn enemies of the Foobarians
> - Refer to their warriors as 'the Barbazians'
> - Insectoids from a very hot planet
>
> ### Characters
>
> #### [Captain Knuckles](http://www.example.com/char-knuckles.html)
>
> - Master swordsman, fearless explorer
>
> #### [First Officer Janet](http://www.example.com/char-janet.html)
>
> - Stern, brilliant pilot
>
> #### [Engineer Jon](http://www.example.com/char-jon.html)
>
> - Hapless and surrounded by incomprehensible [alien tech](http://www.example.com/alien-artifacts.html).

etc, etc. Each link should take you to more detailed information. The character links for example, might link to a mini-biography, description and selection of quotes.
(Click edit if you want to see how I made that list)
The index can link to more detailed lists, as well, depending on the size of your world. A section titled "Alien Tech" might link to sub lists entitled "Games", "Faster than Light", "Communication", etc. For a fantasy world, replace "Tech" with "Magic", etc.

*This makes for easy cross-referencing, which is as simple as linking to the right page.*

### Can I try Markdown

Sure, markdown is *free*. You will want to ask on another StackExchange for detailed installation instructions, but it should be as simple as installing [perl](https://www.perl.org/get.html) and downloading [markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).

Answer (score 1):

Scrivener is a good organizer for writers and such.

Organizing lore in it should be easy, though the software is not for free although not that costly.

Comment: Agreed. Scrivener is what I use. If the OP wanted something completely free (well, free if you have a PC with Office installed that is) MS OneNote could also work. But Scrivener is far superior for this purpose IMO

Comment: Wow...someone beat Monica to pimping scrivener :)

Comment: Joze, I have marked this question as a duplicate but I don't believe anyone mentioned Scrivener as an answer in the other question so you may want to post an answer there.  Please provide more detail \functionality in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to mind would be to create HTML pages for each entry. Have an index page, which just holds a list of links to the various categories. Under each category, you could include more links to other topics.

E.g. the index could have a link to "Mythology", which could be subdivided into the various civilisations ("Bardoopia" and "Nuubery" for the sake of an exmaple). Under "Bardoopia", you could include links to the Legends of Trololo, Ish-Kohn and Diddlee-Duu, while the mythology page for Nuubery could hold links to the tale of Les Pycrab and so on. You could even cross-reference other pages (such as what the inhabitants of Nuubery think of the Legends of Trololo).

Silly names aside, this *does* require you to have some basic knowledge of HTML. However, HTML is quite easy to learn, so once you have that you can extend your encyclopedia relatively easily, and it would run quite easily in any browser. The pages can just be in a folder on your desktop, so it doesn't need an Internet connection, and you edit the files with any text editor (such as the bog-standard one that comes with Windows), so it shouldn't cost anything other than time.